# VBA: Macro terminates when open new workbook? How to avoid?

Tags: excel, vba

When prompting the user to select Wb - which I read the name from and later open - my macro terminates or something like that.. (At this line: "Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sSourceDir"). How kan I keep the macro running?

```
Sub AppendCognosData()

Dim sSourceDir As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSourceFile, sImportSheet2 As String
Dim vfilename, vImportSheet As Variant
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim SourceWs As Worksheet

MsgBox "Select a continuous range of cells (in a column) where numeric values should be appended."

Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8) 'Type Values, 8 - Range object

'Create Ws and Wb for Destionation
Set AppendWs = Worksheets(Rng.Parent.Name)
Set AppendWb = Workbooks(Rng.Parent.Parent.Name)

'Read new range object in input file

sSourceDir = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook", MultiSelect:=False) 'added MultiSelect:=False
If sSourceDir = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected!"
    Exit Sub

Else
    vfilename = Split(sSourceDir, "\")
    sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename)) 'Get filename incl. format from filepath directory
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sSourceDir 'Open the Wb

    vSourceFile = Split(sFile, ".")
    sSourceWb = vSourceFile(0) 'Read open Workbook's name

    Set SourceWb = Workbooks(sFile)     

End If
End Sub
```

- After I've open the new Wb I want the user to select a range - i.e. use the "Set Rng2".

*After that I will do stuff when I have 2 ranges defined in the 2 different Wb's.*

Comment: What is the error message your getting?  What value are you entering into the input box ?

Comment: Don't get any error code at all, feels like it just ignores continue running the macro since another Excel-activity was launeched - namely the new Workbook which was opened through the VBA...